# C# TCP add Client thread-safe List<T>

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

In the below code I am adding new clients to the `clientList`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
        private int appStatus = 0;
        TcpClient client;
        TcpClient streamData;
        List<TcpClient> clientList = new List<TcpClient>();
        NetworkStream networkStream;
        Thread th_StartListen, th_inPutStream, th_outPutStream, th_checkConnection;
        StringBuilder strOutput;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            customizeDesign();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th_StartListen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListen));
            th_StartListen.Start();
            txtCmdOutput.Focus();
        }


        private void StartListen()
        {
            //Creating a TCP Connection and listening to the port
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 6666);
            tcpListener.Start();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Listening on port 6666 ...";
            int counter = 0;
            appStatus = 0;

            
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    counter++;
                    clientList.Add(client);

                    clientList.AsParallel().ForAll(item => clientList.Add(client));

                    
                    Parallel.ForEach(clientList, item =>
                    {
                        lock (clientList)
                            clientList.Add(client);
                    });



                    IPEndPoint ipend = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
                    //Updating status of connection
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected from " + IPAddress.Parse(ipend.Address.ToString());
                    appStatus = 1;
                    
                    th_outPutStream = new Thread(delegate () { outPutStream(client); });
                    th_outPutStream.Start();
                    th_inPutStream = new Thread(delegate () { inPutStream(client); });
                    th_inPutStream.Start();
                    th_checkConnection = new Thread(checkConnection);
                    th_checkConnection.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    {
                        Cleanup();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I was advised that using a `non-thread-safe List<T>` to keep a list of clients is not a good solution.

So I was wondering how I could apply a `thread-safe List<T>` as to add the clients without encountering any errors.

So I attempted to do the following:

```cs
clientList.AsParallel().ForAll(item => clientList.Add(client));
```

Could anyone suggest a correct methodology?

Is the above code thread-safe? Is there a chance of the processed list getting could get corrupted? Or should I use a lock before adding?

```
Parallel.ForEach(clientList, item =>
                    {
                        lock (clientList)
                            clientList.Add(client);
                    });
```

Comment: You are using the *non-thread-safe `List<T>`* from one thread, which is what it was designed for.

Comment: Do you know why it would not be a good solution?

Comment: There is a whole namespace for Concurrent collections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-7.0 each with its own capabilities / usage scenario.

Comment: @user253751 yes I do understand, but I tried to apply the "Thread safe" list solution as shown in the body of this message, but they didn't seem to work..

Comment: then tell me to make sure you know: Why is a non-thread-safe list not a good solution?

Comment: That `StartListen` method looks like to be started from a UI thread. Is it? Because in that case you block the UI thread due to the while(true) loop.

Comment: @user253751 Because accessing and modifying the list simultaneously by multiple threads will return in errors because the list can only be accessed in order. so if two threads try to append a single list at same time, this will cause an error... I do understand what this means...And that Is not my question. I am just trying to understand how to apply a thread-safe List<T>

Comment: Where is the list accessed from multiple threads?

Comment: @rene yes that is correct. Once a client connects, the three threads run(Updating some information) and returns to the client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); section and waits for new client.

Comment: @GSerg , well that is the thing, so far I was working on a 1 to 1 connection between server and client, and now I am trying to implement a one to many connection from server to client. I have updated my initial message to show the entire first part of the script

Comment: The first thing to understand about thread safety is that thread safety is something a *whole program* is (or at least the part that has threads), not just one tiny part of a program like a list. You can still make a not-thread-safe program using thread-safe lists, and you can make a thread-safe program using not-thread-safe lists too. Even if you use a thread-safe list, if you do something like `if(!clients.Empty()) firstClient = clients.Get(1);` that's not thread-safe. Thread-safetyness permeates every line of code.

Comment: The number of connections to the clients does not matter. You only have one thread that adds entries to `clientList`.

Comment: @user253751 thanks for that explanation, I believe I understand your point. Because I was under the illusion that as I might be interacting with multiple clients at the same time, that they would need to access the list simultaneously. In essence I would always be interacting with one client at a time, but incase a new client joins whilst im performing and an action with another.

Comment: @King it doesn't matter whether another thread is doing *something*. To have a thread-safety problem you need two threads to do something *with that list* at the same time. Which I guess don't do now, but they will do soon when you add your one-to-many feature.

Comment: btw thread-safety is often much harder to do than simply doing everything on one thread. Threads are the norm in Java but you are using .NET so you have good ability to do multiple things on one thread by using BeginAccept, BeginReceive, BeginSend, etc

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I was very much confused on this subject... please feel free to post your answers and il vote it. Thanks!